# QGIS Print Layout Vertical Graduated or Continous Legend Bar

Tags: qgis, legend, layout-manager

I would like to replicate a legend bar design from a map that I assume comes out of ArcGIS:

[image: Continuous Legend Bar]

Is this possible in QGIS without using external software like illustrator?

Comment: Does your scale bar need to be dynamic, i.e. will the underlying data change? For my part, for one set of results I would just do a little of it based on the dataset and a lot of it with static text boxes.

Comment: No, the data (range) will not change... So you create it in an image processing/ illustratir type tool?